# Can't seem to zip up xml file correctly using C#

Tags: c#, xml, compression, nopcommerce

Ok so I have tried numerous examples on the web, but I can't seem to get any working.

I have the following code which creates a zip archive, and when I extract the zip archive there is a xml file.

```
string filePathZip = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "content\\files\\exportimport",
                prependStoreId + "ebayproductinventorysyncfeed.zip");

                using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(filePathZip, (!File.Exists(filePathZip)) ? FileMode.CreateNew : FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                    {
                        //byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(oldFilePath);
                        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(oldFilePath);
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                        {
                            writer.Write(oldFilePath);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                            Debug.WriteLine("========================");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now the problem is if I open that xml file the data from the original xml file is not there. So instead of seeing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <Version>967</Version>
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
```

I get this:

```
C:\projects\website\Presentation\Nop.Web\content\files\exportimport\ebaylmsinventoryfeed.xml
```

I figure it's something to do with opening the file as a stream, just can't figure it out as I'm fairly new to C#.

I have also tried:

```
writer.Write(bytes);
```

Can anyone help, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get this:
>
> `C:\projects\website\Presentation\Nop.Web\content\files\exportimport\ebaylmsinventoryfeed.xml`

That's what you told it to do:

```
writer.Write(oldFilePath);
```

Perhaps instead:

```
using (var dest = readmeEntry.Open()))
using (var source = File.OpenRead(oldFilePath))
{
    source.CopyTo(dest);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped, but I had to use this to get it to work properly `source.CopyTo(writer.BaseStream);`

Comment: @chrisc look again at my code: I don't even *have* a `writer`... this is not a mistake; the `writer` here is completely unnecessary

Comment: Ahh yep I see what you have done here. Works a charm thanks m8 :)